# Adjusting ComboBox DropDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I currently have this XAML/C# which does exactly what I want when I click on the ComboBox to drop down; It shows all the items in the list.

```
// XAML
<ComboBox Name="MyCB" />
// C# Code behind:
MyCB.ItemsSource = MyModel.MyProperty;
```

When I takeout the code behind and just use XAML, the ComboBox drop down changes itself to show only a few items and puts in a scroll bar.

```
// XAML
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}" DataContext="{Binding MyModel}"/>
```

What do I need to change to the XAML only code so I can have the same visual result as the XAML/C# code? I have did some research and playing with DropDownHeight doesn't seem to help.